# Ensure I always overwrite ios app on upgrade

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I am about to launch an update to my app that was previously built by a separate developer. I want to make sure that I transition the app to my team however I need to make sure the app I publish will upgrade the users existing app and not install a new one. I am using the same app identifier but do I also need to use the same certificate and provisioning profile?

Any help is appreciated

Comment: As long as you use the same bundle id and you submit the app as an update to the existing app in iTunes Connect, the user will see the app as an update, not a new app.

Comment: I heard that if you use a different provision profile it will install a new app instead of overrighting. Not true?

Comment: Not true at all. You need to create a new certificate every year (requiring new provisioning profiles) and it's quite common to create new provisioning profiles all of the time (new devices, updated app capabilities). None of that has any effect related to your question.

Comment: If you are using same bundle Id then it will automatic override the previous app, profile doesn't matter. Btw We have already did this with two live apps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as the bundle id is the same, it will overwrite the existing app.  We use different bundle IDs for our different build configurations (one for when it is built from a developer's Mac, one from when it is built by our CI box, and one when we build for the app store).  We used to use one bundle ID, and it would overwrite the prod build when a developer built to the device (not always what we want).

You may be thinking of Android, which will behave a bit differently if you have your APK signed differently.  I believe it will still replace the existing app, but it will force you to do an uninstall first, so you cannot do an upgrade install on Android if the apps were signed differently (i.e. one app is installed with your distribution key, the other with a dev key).