# iOS App update code conflicts if completely new app?

Tags: ios, xcode

I got a semi-programming related question to iOS app updates. Hopefully this isn't off topic.

OK, so lets say I got a version 1 of the app built by developer A and the app gets released on the app store.

Fast forward a year later, developer B comes along and builds the same app from scratch without using any code from developer A or the project files. However, developer B makes sure the same bundle ID is used.

Now if developer B logs into the same iTunes connect account, creates a new app update to the existing app and submits the next version of the app using his own code but exactly same bundle ID, will there be any code conflict from the end user's point of view?

Will the app crash if existing users of the app running version 1 installs version 2?

I'm speculating right now that it should work so as long as the bundle ID is the same but hopefully someone else has done this before and can tell me if there's any problem with this approach.

Ideally, we want to create an update instead of launching it as a new app so that previous users see a update app notification but we don't want to risk getting rejected by Apple because we have an event date to meet.

Comment: App updates essentially overwrite the existing application on the device. They do not overwrite the documents folder, so it's perfectly feasible for you to do what you describe.

Comment: Also, if you have an event date to meet, you can request an 'expedited review' from apple and select 'time sensitive event' as a reason.

Comment: Alright, thanks that's reassuring. I also found this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24837003/ensure-i-always-overwrite-ios-app-on-upgrade so that's double reassuring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App updates essentially overwrite the existing application on the device. They do not overwrite the documents folder, so it's perfectly feasible for you to do what you describe.

Also, if you have an event date to meet, you can request an 'expedited review' from apple and select 'time sensitive event' as a reason

Comment: +1 for the expedite review. Reference page on how to request expedite review: https://developer.apple.com/support/appstore/app-review/ you need to click this line apparently: https://developer.apple.com/appstore/contact/?topic=expedite

Comment: No cost, but it's not guaranteed. If it is my experience is that it's reviewed and released on day of submission/request. Depending on your timezone of course.